# Haml / Rails 4: Conditions - repeating code inside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

How can I make something like this work with haml/rails:

```
- if current_user.is_seeking_job == true && current_user.is_seeking_contract == true
  - @jobsforyou.where.not(user_id: current_user, is_finished: true, is_active: false).where("sort < ?", 2).limit(10).each do |job|
- else
  - @jobsforyou.where.not(user_id: current_user, is_finished: true, is_active: false).where("sort > ?", 1).limit(10).each do |job|
    %li
```

Obviously I get an error because I have no code inside the first loop.
The thing is that I have more than these two conditions and inside of `%li` is a lot of code.
Of course I could just copy it for each condition and it would work, but how can do that without copying the same piece of code over and over again?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This question is probably better suited to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), rather than here. I would also recommend that you post a more complete version of the code -- it's hard to give advice when missing potentially important pieces of information!

Comment: On the basis of the code you've posted the obvious thing would be to delete the useless loop entirely - if you can clarify why you can't do that you might get a more helpful answer.

Comment: @Gugubaight this logic must be handled in controller. its very bad practice to add such conditions in views.

Comment: I added this to my controller based on the answer by pdoherty926 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
- if current_user.is_seeking_job && current_user.is_seeking_contract
  - sort_order = "sort < ?"
  - sort_param = 2
- else
  - sort_order = "sort > ?"
  - sort_param = 1
- @jobsforyou.where.not(user_id: current_user, is_finished: true, is_active: false).where(sort_order, sort_param).limit(10).each do |job|
```

However, this solution is a violation of the [separation of concerns principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) - your view should (ideally) only be displaying data, not querying the database. I'd suggest moving the queries and associated logic somewhere more appropriate, like model methods or scopes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I added this to my controller based on your answer :-)